# How to delete HTML tags, not the contents in Vim

Tags: html, vim, keyboard-shortcuts, janus

I have the following piece of code in a file that I opened in `Vim`:

```
<p>Hello stackoverflow!</p>
```

How can I delete `<p>` and `</p>` tags but keep the contents between them? That is, what should I press to end with:

```
Hello stackoverflow!
```

I know pressing <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> will do opposite.

I'm using [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus).

Answer (score 108, accepted):

With the [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin installed, press <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to **d**elete **s**urrounding **t**ag.

Similar shortcuts:

- <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>(</kbd> - delete surrounding parentheses `()`
- <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> - delete surrounding double quotes `""`
- <kbd>d</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>'</kbd> - delete surrounding single quotes `''`

and so on...

Comment: That's solution for me. Thank you.

Comment: This should be most upvoted answer, as everyone should be using TPopes awesome plugin these days! :)

Comment: I knew about `di…` and `da…` but I just learnt about `ds…`. So useful!

Answer (score 100):

A simple solution would be (with the cursor anywhere inside the tag):

```
yitvatp
```

What this does is:

- `y` - yanks
- `it` - the inside of the tag
- `vat` - selects the entire tag
- `p` - pastes the previously yanked text over it

Comment: Really nice Randy!
I'm using surround.vim plugin, so Benoit's answer is really solution for me.

Comment: Very nice. I posted a supplemental answer to give a bit more details. Thanks Randy!

Comment: Super! I was almost ready ask similar question, but found your answer. Thanks!

Comment: yitvatp=at for the compulsive.

Answer (score 6):

Love Randy's (+1) answer and I just learned about tag blocks! This is just a supplemental answer.

So yit means "yank inner tag block" and vat means "go to visual mode and select *a* (whole) tag block".

This is just for those that are too lazy to read the help file:

```
Tag blocks                      *tag-blocks*

For the "it" and "at" text objects an attempt is done to select blocks between
matching tags for HTML and XML.  But since these are not completely compatible
there are a few restrictions.

The normal method is to select a <tag> until the matching </tag>.  For "at"
the tags are included, for "it" they are excluded.  But when "it" is repeated
the tags will be included (otherwise nothing would change).  Also, "it" used
on a tag block with no contents will select the leading tag.

"<aaa/>" items are skipped.  Case is ignored, also for XML where case does
matter.

In HTML it is possible to have a tag like <br> or <meta ...> without a
matching end tag.  These are ignored.

The text objects are tolerant about mistakes.  Stray end tags are ignored.
```

Answer (score 4):

Map this to a key of your choice:

```
vat<Esc>da>`<da>
```

Taken from http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Delete_a_pair_of_XML/HTML_tags

Comment: Thank you, I saw that too. But I want to map it in same way like dit. For example to dot.

Comment: @retro it is generally not a good idea to map it to "dot" since that shadows other very handy vim commands, i.e. "single-repeat"

Answer (score 0):

I tried the dst solution with surround.vim on a larger html block. It works but it indents all child tags to the same level. It shouldn't change the indentation, messes everything up.

Randys solution with yitvatp works too, but leaves me with a blank line before and after the pasted tag.

Any perfect solution out there?